# set scrolling step in flex horizontal scroller

Tags: flash, apache-flex, scroll

My current flex scroller component is scrolling in way too small steps. I cannot find a property which would increase the step of the scrolling, or do I have to subclass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the mouseWheel event

```
foo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, foo_mouseWheelHandler);
```

and increase/decrease the horizontalScrollPosition with multiples of event.delta

```
protected function foo_mouseWheelHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{           
    foo.viewport.horizontalScrollPosition -= (event.delta * 50);
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works, please correct your answer - foo.viewport.horizontalScrollPosition